How to keep the last active file highlighted after closing its editor in VS Code
Currently, when I navigate to a code editor by clicking its tab among the opened files, its source file in the browser gets highlighted. That's fine. However, what I want is when closing that active file, I need that same file highlighted. I do not want VS Code to highlight the newly active file except if I manually click it.
